# Limit rows in bar charts and interactive report in APEX5.0

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using bar charts and interactive reports in APEX 5.0 and I want to set the maximum count for number of records to be displayed on the chart and interactive report.I am unable to find the attributes for chart and report where I can set the maximum records.I am looking for information on following:

- How to set maximum records to display on charts and reports?
- For the interactive report I want to display first n records and add a pagination so that more records can be displayed on demand.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

for limiting the chart data you may use following query style

```
select *
from  
    ( select * 
      from YOUR_TABLE
      order by YOUR_FIELD desc ) 
    where ROWNUM <= 5;
```

for the interactive reports

- login to apex development enviroment
- run your application
- while you are running report get in to actions->rows per page -> x
- then save the report by choosing save report and choose as default report option 
  so that all users will have the configuration you made